# Do multiple structured data elements compete for display in SERPS?

Tags: seo, google-search, microdata, rich-snippets, schema.org

For example, with a product page you may have product info (price, offers, image etc.) but also have a video to show the context of use of the product. I don't believe the product structured data contains a nested video element, so would this be added separately?

How would this affect the rich snippets in SERPs? Would one snippet be prioritised over the other? Would both be shown? Would google analyse intent to choose what to display?

Answer (score 1):

Google has stated, that structured data is not currently used for **featured snippets**.

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-structured-data-not-featured-snippets-21206.html

Other than that, it is not known (not publicly announced) that structured data elements compete for being displayed in SERPs in any ways.

Comment: But this is only about the "featured snippets", not for other SERP features (i.e., rich snippets).

Comment: @unor yes, sorry, my bad, I overlooked the question